# Вопрос по приведению интерфейсов Golang

Tags: golang

Имеется следующий код:

```
type NoUpd struct{}

func (n NoUpd) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Нет обновлений")
}

type Err struct{}

func (e Err) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Ошибка")
}

func makeErr() error {
    return Err{}
}

func main() {
    val, ok := makeErr().(NoUpd)
    fmt.Println(val, ok)
}
```

При выполнении получаю:

> Нет обновлений false

Вернул я тип Err, который привёлся к типу NoUpd, хотя ok == false

Как это работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понял что вы хотите сделать, но если вопрос в том как это работает, то это легко понять добавив какую-то переменную в структуры.
Что-то вроде

```
type NoUpd struct{ msg string }

func (n NoUpd) Error() string { return n.msg }
```

**Утверждение типа вернет *нулевое значение типа*, если проверка не прошла и ok будет равен false.** У нулевого значения типа будет весь набор методов, а вот все члены структуры будут нулевыми значениями. Поэтому вы и видите сообщение об ошибке обновления, но это сообщение относится к новой переменной типа NoUpd. Добавив msg видно, что значение теряется.

Полный код примера

```
package main

import "fmt"

type NoUpd struct{ msg string }

func (n NoUpd) Error() string { return n.msg }

type Err struct{ msg string }

func (e Err) Error() string { return e.msg }

func makeErr() error {
    return Err{"Ошибка"}
}

func main() {
    val, ok := makeErr().(NoUpd)
    fmt.Println(val, ok)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но я спрашивал об этом 2 года назад, сейчас уже всё сам понимаю)

Answer (score 0):

У вас какое-то странное представление утверждений типа. `v, ok = err.(NoUpd)` проверяет только то, является ли значение внутри интерфейса значением типа `NoUpd`. Тип `Err` тут вообще ни при чём. Хотите проверять на `Err`, то так и пишите.